# Single column dataframe with years and content to multiple columns matching content with each year

Tags: r

I scraped some data from Wikipedia and am having a hard time figuring out how to manipulate it into the format I need it. Here is a subset of the data in its current form for reference:

```
1961[26]
"Theme from A Summer Place"
"Are You Lonesome Tonight?"
"Georgia on My Mind"
"Mack the Knife"
"Nice 'n' Easy"
1962[27]
"Moon River"
"Big Bad John"
"The Second Time Around"
"Take Five"
"(Up a) Lazy River"
```

I would like to do 2 things: indicate the first record after the year as the winner in some way, and also to pair the year with the song titles between that year and the next year. Any ideas would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the format you need

Comment: Add expected output and also add what you tried..